# Ubuntu Server Installation getting Stuck

Tags: server, system-installation

I am trying to install the latest Ubuntu server edition on a machine with 2 CPUs and 128GB DDR3 RAM.

However, the installation getting stuck when I click on 'Install Ubuntu Server'.

The CD Drive doesn't seem to be reading anything from the CD, After a while It is stopping and green light is getting off. I have checked CD disk on another machine, It is working fine.

Please help.

The error message shown is `EDD:Error 8000 reading sector 42127`

Comment: Are you able to run live server, means without installing are you able to go to desktop using try option.

Comment: I am booting from CD. There is no 'run live server' option

Comment: Please confirm which version of **Ubuntu** you are installing. Is this is fact a DVD (not a CD)? How did you create the DVD, and on what OS? *It may be a kernel/compatibility issue.*

Comment: Hi, the version is 14.04 LTS and I have burned the IOS image to a CD using the disk image burner provided by the windows system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone! I have found the answer.

I changed the disk mode in the BOIS settings from RAID to AHCI and then everything started working. I suspect that Intel RAID controller was the one causing probelms.

Answer (score 2):

It Might be problem of your Disk Drive, OR CD,if one of these two are very old then change them, as you are saying that you have checked it on another machine then it could be a problem of disk drive. I also used to get error when I was trying to install from my old Disk Drive Try installing from a new usb disk drive or make a bootable pendrive from the disk using that checked machine.

and see this question might be help you.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121047/error-8000-bad-sectors-when-installing-centos-6-5-minimum

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much info to go off of here, but changing to another TTY and looking through the contents of `/var/log/dmesg` or `/var/log/kern.log` might lead you in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command and then try to install,

```
sudo apt-get install -fy

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y

sudo reboot now
```

Comment: May I know where can I type in the command?